# IdentityServer4 OpenIdConnectAuthentication or IdentityServerAuthentication

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

When configuring IdentityServer4 for ASP WebAPI/MVC i have the option to use

- app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
- app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication

It seems to me that it does the same thing. Why shouldi choose the Identity server option over the openidconnect?

When does each one apply best and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In API (MVC Web API) application you should call

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication
```

See [IdentityServer4 API documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html)

> Our authentication middleware serves the same purpose as the app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication
>   middleware (in fact it uses the Microsoft JWT middleware  internally),
>   but adds a couple of additional features:
>
> - support for both JWTs and reference tokens
> - extensible caching for  reference tokens
> - unified configuration model
> - scope validation

In Web Client (MVC Web ) you should call

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication
```

See [IdentityServer4 "Creating an MVC client" documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html?highlight=UseIdentityServerAuthentication)

Answer (score 0):

#### *app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication*

It implement a middlware to use the OIC flow whatever your server authority.

Have a look on those links :

- https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-openid-connect-in-asp-net-core/
- https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core
- https://grean.com/easyid/aspnetcore/oidc/2017/02/25/aspnet-core-and-easyid.html

#### *app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication*

In this case, the configuration is more specific to use the IdendityServer4 workflow

#### Difference ?

The first is more generic whereas the second is more specific.